# iPhone, can I create retina quality screen shots without an iPhone 4, e.g. simulator perhaps?

Tags: iphone

I need to produce some quality screen shots of screens in my app.

I'd like to use them as a backgrounds in some help screens.

But I don't have an iPhone 4.

How else can I create them ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up the simulator as an iPhone 4 and run it in that.  The simulator window will be huge (because it will display the same number of pixels as the retina display on your computers lower pixel density screen.)  Then, take a screenshot of that! (use grab or whatever screenshot app you'd like!

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: I've tried simulator 4.1 which didn't seem big, is that what you mean?

Comment: You have to go in the menu to "Hardware" - "Device" - "iPhone4". Then you will have the "big" iPhone with the Retina resolution...

Comment: Oh, that's in the simulator's menus while it's running.  This should be in the answer.